# firebase onAuthStateChanged not working on two identical projects

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I was working on a React project at the time. I'm using `onAuthStateChanged()` to track the user authentication state, so I rebuilt the same project for practice, but the same code works in my first project but not in the rebuilt version. everything is the same even the firebaseConfig and file structure.

p.s Other changes properly reflecting on firebase console e.g `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, `signInWithPopup`, `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` except `onAuthStateChanged()` is not detecting any changes.

**firebase config -**

```
export const onAuthStateChangedListner = callback => onAuthStateChanged(auth, callback);
```

**User Authentication Context -**

```
   React.useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChangedListner(user => {
         setCurrentUser(user);
      });
      return unsubscribe;
   }, [currentUser]);
```

**Main APP -**

```
function App() {
   const { currentUser } = React.useContext(UserAuthContext);

   if (currentUser) {
      return <HomePage />;
   } else {
      return <AuthenticationPage />;
   }
}
```